How to create a frame with two parts
I am trying to create a frame with two parts. Both connected like in the picture below. I want to use it to write whatever I want in it and I do not need any counters. I want to do the counters myself. I have tried to use a theorem box but it is not what I want.

I want to be able to use this theorem counter inside it separately. Advanced hierarchical counting for theorems
So, just want to do the box with no counters.
Thank you

Package tcolorbox, or nodes with multiparts (pgfmanual) might work.

As the question is, the answer could be the answer could be  just \begin{tabular}{|l|} \hline foo \\\hline bah \\\hline \end{tabular}  or   "run  texdoc tcolorbox, see page 12".  You may have to work on the question by adding a minimum example document with your best attempt with  these or another approaches, and clearly explaining what is missing or what is left over in that example.

By the way, the title of this question might be a bit misleading as there is a famous LaTeX package for creating presentations called "beamer" in which each presentation slide is called a "frame".

Thank you for letting me know. I was not aware of this. Please feel free to make any changes.

The package tcolorbox (https://ctan.org/pkg/tcolorbox) does probably everything that you would like to do. Here is an example:
\documentclass[english,11pt,a5paper]{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{skins,breakable}

\newtcolorbox{MyQuestion}[2][]{%
    enhanced, breakable, 
    title style={green!30}, % background color of the top field
    colback=red!5,        % background color of the bottom field
    colframe=blue!65,       % color of the frame
    width=\textwidth,       % width of the box
    %
    sharp corners,          % or use `arc=6pt` instead of `sharp corners`  
    %
    boxsep=5pt,             % space around the title text
    left=6pt,right=6pt,     % spacing of text inside the box
    top=5pt,bottom=5pt,  
    %
    bottomrule=3pt, toprule=5pt,  % thicknesses of various lines
    leftrule=1pt, rightrule=1pt,
    titlerule=1pt, 
    %
    title={\color{red}#2}, 
    #1                      % everything that is inside [] of \begin{MyQuestion}[]
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{MyQuestion}{%
        Question 1. So, I was taking a walk the other day. 
        And I see a woman pacing up and down ...
    }
        Solution:  ... \\
    \end{MyQuestion}
\end{document}

which looks like this:

I intentionally chose a few different colors to make changing them easier.
Even though you said that you will "manually" take care of counters, it might be helpful to know that tcolorboxes also support custom counters for environments (just search for "counters" in the tcolorbox documentation that you can find at the above given link).
